# Get an attribute name with document.getelementbyid in js

Tags: javascript

Why is it doesn't work?

```js
var x = document.getElementById('test').name;
alert(x); // jhon
```

```html
<div id='test' name='jhon'> its just a text </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Div elements are not allowed `name` attributes, so there is no matching property for them on the DOM.

If you want to store custom data on an element, use a `data-*` attribute.

If you really want to use invalid HTML you can access it with the `getAttribute` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use getAttribute method to get value of any attribute of html element

```js
   var x = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute("name");
   console.log(x)
```

```html
<div id='test' name='jhon'> its just a text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 var x = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('name')
```